# How to deploy a python wheel using poetry & databricks bundle assets?

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-asset-bundle

I'm trying to run this tutorial : Develop a Python wheel by using Databricks Asset Bundles on this link : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/bundles/python-wheel

I have a problem when using this block code:

artifacts:
default:
type: whl
build: poetry build
path: .

I get this error ( not very explicite):
Building default...
Error: build failed default, error: exit status 1, output:

Note : databricks bundle validate run successfully.
databricks bundle deploy -t dev Fails.

I have same configuration on my local machine :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YzHt3.png)

the reste of code is same as in the tutorial.

Note : When I build my wheel locally with poetry build then deploy, it works.
When I build the wheel and keep the artifacts block , when running deploy the generated wheel will disapear o.o

Anyone can help ?
Poetry version 1.7
Databricks CLI version v0.212.0
Python 3.11

The expected behaviour is to copy files and wheel to the databricks remote workspace.

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurres when trying to deploy Databrciks Assets Bundles using poetry locally.

When I deployed the bundle (with the artifact block) using Azure DevOps Pipeline, I didn't face the problem.